# Is linear kernel positive definite?

Tags: matlab, kernel, svm, inner-product

In a lot of articles, the linear kernel (inner product of two matrices) is listed as positive definite however when I try it with a toy dataset, positive definiteness test returns negative result. I checked the MATLAB SVM function for linear kernel.

The linear kernel function is one line command,

```
K=(u*v')
```

However after this step in the main svm_train function it does another operation using K,

```
kx= (kx+kx')/2 + diag(1./boxconstraint)
```

Where `kx` is K and `diag(1./boxconstraint)` is just a diagonal matrix of size `kx` and resultant `kx` pass the positive definiteness test. As an explanation of this step it says
`'% ensure function is symmetric.'` I also checked `libsvm` but I could not find this additional operation there.

However the inner product is already symmetric and this step is usually used to turn indefinite matrices into positive definite matrices. I am a bit confused about why inner product kernel does not pass the positive definiteness test?

Comment: Sorry I don't know anything about SVNs or what you refer to as a "linear kernel". What are `u` and `v`? I assume that they're square matrices, but where do they come from and what properties do they have? Hermitian?

Comment: for svm_train u and v refers to training data and they are the same mxn matrices. m is the number of training instances and n is the number of dimensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If u,v are both row vectors (i.e. K evaluates to a scalar), K will only be positive definite if K=dot(u,v)>0.

If u and v are more general matrices (not row vectors) and u~=v, then K=u*v' will not generally be symmetric, let alone positive definite. Even when u=v, K will be non-negative definite, but will not be *strictly* positive definite unless u has full row rank. However, the additional matrix 1./diag(boxconstraint) is strictly positive definite assuming all boxconstraint(i)>0. Adding a non-negative definite matrix to a strictly positive definite matrix produces a strictly positive definite result always.

Answer (score 0):

OK, what you say makes sense actually, when I create a toy dataset with a full row rank, inner product matrix becomes positive definite. If there is even two linear dependent rows then it is not positive definite anymore. I'll accept your answer. Thanks.